# Problems with file sitemap.xml for Google

Tags: seo, sitemap, google-search

Google Search Console can not indexing my site Idei.by - when I try to send any page of site to index, Console shows me that mistake:
"In your Sitemap or in the index file of the Sitemap namespace written incorrectly"
What does it wants???!!! No idea!!! Please, help!!! Need indexing this site quickly.

> Framework: Symphony 4.3.5
>
> Our sitemap: http://www.idei.by/sitemap.xml
>
> Our robots.txt: view-source:http://www.idei.by/robots.txt